# Stop child job when parent job is aborted

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have 3 jobs on Jenkins organized as follows:

```
                         --> Job B (conf 1) --> Job C
Job A (MULTI CONF JOB)--|
                         --> Job B (Conf 2) --> Job C
```

Job a calls job b (with specific conf) and job b when finished calls job C

When I stop (abort Job A) job B continues, how can I configure Job A to stop his child job B ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can come up with is to have the child job run a "nanny" process which polls the parent job to see if it's still running. If it's no longer running it will kill the child job, either via a REST call or just by killing the job step process.

Answer (score 0):

If the child jobs are configured to start based on the result of parent job, this can be achieved by selecting the pre/post build action options.

```
    Trigger only if build is stable 

    Trigger even if the build is unstable   

    Trigger even if the build fails
```

However how the setup is done for the 3 three jobs mentioned. Three independent jobs ? if job B is started only after completion of job A(either success/failure/abort) above options will be helpful.

If you have configured job B to start even if the build fails/abort of job A, then job B continues to run.

Comment: The Job A waits completion of job B (blocker), the job A is only to select parameters to use in the Job B.